# Why does one value keep appearing larger than the other?

Tags: java, if-statement, statements

So I'm trying to do this small program as a exercise for class and I honestly cannot figure out why the value for x keeps replacing w.  Could someone explain to me why this is happening. I know ASCII-wise w has a smaller value than x so i genuinely don't understand.
    import java.util.*;

```
public class SmallestIntMod
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a value for w: ");
    int w = scan.nextInt();
    int smallest = w;
    System.out.println("Enter a value for x: ");
    int x = scan.nextInt();
    if (x < smallest);
    {
      smallest = x;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a value for y: ");
    int y = scan.nextInt();
    if (y < smallest)
    {
      smallest = y;
    }
    System.out.println("Enter a value for z: ");
    int z = scan.nextInt();
    if (z < smallest)
    {
      smallest = z;
    }
    System.out.println("The smallest value is: " + smallest);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `;` :

```
if (x < smallest);
                 ^
{
  smallest = x;
}
```

The semi-colon ends the if statement, so the following block gets executed every time, regardless of the values of `x` and `smallest`.